# need help cleaning a sound sample from a constant (stationary) background noise

Tags: sound

I have been recording sound sample from mouse vocalisations and noticed that a background noise appeared in the recording room. the noise is clearly visible in the spectrograms of the recordings as horizontal lines at frequencies 20, 40, 60, 80, and 100 kHz (ultrasonic range).
I have tried to record in an acoustically isolated box, lined with sound absorbing material, and it helps, however, the box retains unwanted odours which effect the behaviour of the mice, rendering it unusable.

My question is if there is a method to isolate and remove the noise without effecting the rest of the sounds. i want to study the vocalisations, with an emphasis on the frequency in which the mice communicate under different social encounters, and having that constant noise in the background may effect the results of the study.

Vocal communications were recorded using a 1/4 inch microphone, connected to a preamplifier and an amplifier (Bruel & Kjaer) from mice. Vocalisations were sampled at 250 kHz with a CED Micro 1401-3 (Cambridge Electronic Design Limited, Sunnyvale, CA).

The samples were recorded using spike2, a "DC removal" filter was added to the recording.
the files were then transferred to Matlab for splicing further analyses.

I know that there is a strict policy here against attaching files to questions, therefor I'm adding a link to the audio sample and the spectrogram

[link to an audio sample and a spectrogram](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cpbQa9kWT9nOgp6QV_sRLVPPv4YKNuah?usp=sharing) via google drive.

Comment: .mat is not really a useful audio format. please provide PCM WAV

Comment: Also, what's the reasoning behind recording at 250kHz?

Comment: Thanks for you comments,
I will submit my question in the site you uggested
I am sampling in such a high frequency in order to get a more data, increasing the definition of the sound.

Comment: It's already been here, yes?  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54813